# Get Font Awesome icon value using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fonts, font-awesome

I'm using font awesome in one of my web apps. I want to get the value of an element with a font awesome class and then do more actions with it. Is this possible?

As an example, here is a clickable grid of possible selections:

[image]

The 'icon' is defined with the following HTML:

```
<span class="icon icon-caret-down pointer-img"></span>
```

And the following CSS:

```
.icon-caret-down:before     {content:"\f0d7";}
```

The problem is that the value is set using CSS. What would the jquery selector be for this type of scenario?

```
$(".pointer-img").click(function(){
   console.log( $(this) );
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would just log the span element in question. It is not possible to select psuedo elements with jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a useful snippet recently, but haven't tried it yet:

```
var content = window.getComputedStyle(
    document.querySelector('.element'), ':before'
).getPropertyValue('content');
```

Or more jQuery-crossbrowser-flavoury:

```
var content = window.getComputedStyle(
    $('.element').get(0), ':before'
).getPropertyValue('content');
```

It seems to work... somehow:
<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ts6jh/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: It worked! This is an absolutely fantastic answer! Thank you so much dude :D

Comment: Be aware, that there could (and will) lurk some cross-browser problems, though. This seems not to work in IE8.

Comment: Yeah I've just been testing it in a few different browsers now. As long as it works in chrome, I'm happy!

Comment: @Nirazul I could get the content when using fontawesome. Please have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/91vg7vtt/. Tell me whats went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, just in case anybody needs it (Thanks to Nirazul!)

```
$(".pointer-img").click(function(){
   var content = window.getComputedStyle(
      $($(this)).get(0), ':before'
   ).getPropertyValue('content');
   console.log(content)
});
```